# AGIC associating rules with defaultaddresspool instead of the newly created pool

Tags: kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I have set up an asp.net application in aks almost similar to this article: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/what-does-it-mean-for-the-application-gateway-ingress-controller/ba-p/2839051

Used helm chart instead so I can do a `helm upgrade --install my-deployment my-chart` instead.

While the App Gateway is associated ok with the aks instance, one issue is the rule is getting associated with the defaultaddresspool and not the newly created backend target and settings from the chart / ingress. I can manually change it in the dropdown but that's not practical with multiple services and one helm chart deploy resets every service rule's association to the defaultaddresspool.

[image]

Can anyone suggest anything obvious I might be missing?

Comment: does the ingress definition in your `my-deployment` helm chart have the annotation  `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway` ?

Comment: yes I have. the backend target and settings show the new guys, it is just making me manually select them right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @YK, your comment had me investigate further. Turns out I had misconfigured the spec rules

I had

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-hostname: <<name>>
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <<name>>
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /swagger/index.html
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .Release.Name }}
            port:
              number: 80
```

because the swagger endpoint was needed for health check

Changing that to

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-hostname: <<name>>
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-path: "/swagger/index.html"

spec:
  rules:
  - host: <<name>>
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .Release.Name }}
            port:
              number: 80
```

corrected it.